# Java read file for the first 3 words of certain line

Tags: java

I am trying to read the first 3 words of a sentence from a text file.
The text file as below shown:

```
No. Name Age
1 Hello 12
Performance: Good
Information for student, Class Allocated:13
No. Name Age
2 Hi 13
Performance: Very Good
Data for student, Class Allocated:1
No. Name Age
3 HelloHello 13
Information for student, Class Allocated:1
```

How i code to read is file is as below shown:

```
while (read.hasNext())
{   
    if (read.next().equals("No.")){
        Eliminate.add(read.nextLine()); //eliminate first line
        No.add(read.next());
        Name.add(read.next());
        Age.add(read.nextInt());
    }
```

This is how i initially read the text file. But how i met a problem which is i need the **Information** part. Meanwhile i try to use back the concept for me to read the information but it seems not working.Logically i am not able to break the while loop, once i break the while loop will stop and wont get for the information.
Below shown the code i tried but not work:

```
while (read.hasNext())
{   
    if (read.next().equals("No.")){
        Eliminate.add(read.nextLine()); //eliminate first line
        No.add(read.next());
        Name.add(read.next());
        Age.add(read.nextInt());
        while (read.hasNext()){
            if (read.next().equals("Information")||read.next().equals("Data")){
                if(read.next().equals("Allocated:")){
                    Classroom.add(read.nextInt());
                }
            }
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

The output that i want is:

```
Name: Hello
Classroom: 13
Name: Hi
Classroom: 1
```

Can anyone help me on this? Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't actually see any sentences in your source data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
that was a mistake, it should be read from a line

Comment: I think you should have also showed us the expected output.  This would make it possible to give you answer written from scratch (which might be the way to go here).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thx for the suggestion, i edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is what your looking for. Look at the documentation for the scanner and you might realise that you wan to reformat your output if possible.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader.fileName)    
Scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*Hello\\s*")
while (sc.hasNext()){
sc.nextInt() \\ = 1
sc.nextInt() \\  = 12
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is scan

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your question you are reading text from a text file , then you can use `BufferedReader` to read each line of file and use `LinkedList` to manage order of line  from your file, After populating line  in `LinkedList` you have to apply business logic to extract data from line.

In below example I have tried to show you my approach of solving problem, after applying business logic I have used a nested inner class `StudentInfo` to store student information.

```
public class StudentInfoReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("path to txt file");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        List<String> fileStrings = new LinkedList<>();
        List<StudentInfo> studentInfoList = new LinkedList<>();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                fileStrings.add(line);
            }
            StudentInfo studentInfo = null;
            for (String s : fileStrings) {
                if (s.startsWith("No.")) {
                    studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
                    studentInfoList.add(studentInfo);
                } else {
                    String[] studentInfoArray = s.split(" ");
                    if (s.startsWith("Performance")) {
                        studentInfoArray = s.split(":");
                        studentInfo.setPerformance(studentInfoArray[1]);
                    } else if (s.startsWith("Information")
                            || s.startsWith("Data")) {
                        System.out.println("s is " + s);

                        studentInfo.setClassroom(studentInfoArray[4].substring(studentInfoArray[4].indexOf(":") + 1, studentInfoArray[4].length()));
                    } else {
                        studentInfo.setNo(studentInfoArray[0]);
                        studentInfo.setName(studentInfoArray[1]);
                        studentInfo.setAge(studentInfoArray[2]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (StudentInfo studentInfoTemp : studentInfoList) {
                System.out.println("No " + studentInfoTemp.getNo());
                System.out.println("Name " + studentInfoTemp.getName());
                System.out.println("Age " + studentInfoTemp.getAge());
                System.out.println("class " + studentInfoTemp.getClassroom());
                System.out.println("");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(stack1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static class StudentInfo {

        String no;
        String name;
        String age;
        String classroom;
        String performance;

        public String getNo() {
            return no;
        }

        public void setNo(String no) {
            this.no = no;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getClassroom() {
            return classroom;
        }

        public void setClassroom(String classroom) {
            this.classroom = classroom;
        }

        public String getPerformance() {
            return performance;
        }

        public void setPerformance(String performance) {
            this.performance = performance;
        }

    }
}
```